# Not static java interface

Tags: java, interface, static

On my journey to learn java I'm coding a mini chess game.
I never understood interfaces, but I decide to to give them a try.

So i created an interface to implement move sets on my chess piece
and my move resolver classes.

Something like this:

```
interface MoveSets {

    LinkedList<MoveSet> moveSets = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<MoveSet> potentialMoveSets = new LinkedList<>();

    LinkedList<MoveSet> allaysMoveSet = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<MoveSet> potentialAllaysMoveSets = new LinkedList<>();

    LinkedList<MoveSet> enemysMoveSets = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<MoveSet> potentialEnemysMoveSets = new LinkedList<>();

}
```

Then, I changed it a bit here and there and though - *that's great, I can put the same piece of code on different classes and change it only once*, but when I finish to code my move resolves I saw `The static field MoveSets.moveSets should be accessed in a static way` notice.

So I read about it a bit, and most of the people out there said that variables on the interfaces are static by default. they also said that we cannot change them to non-static variables.

So my questions are if there is any work around for it? if not, there is another way to put the same piece of code in different classes without make the variables static?

I always though that interfaces a ways to connect similar attributes in different class.

But if they are so strict, what I can do with them (outside of
remind myself what methods I should put or force global variables)?

Thanks in advance,

Or

Comment: That isn't a typical use for an interface, and is not how I would start creating interface-based applications. Instead, I'd try to extract methods that are used in more than one class or potential class, and extract out interface methods from your existing classes. I would take all that code  out of this interface first and foremost.

Comment: Better to have an interface for say `ChessPiece` and give it `public boolean isMoveValid(Position p);`, `public void makeMove(Position p);` public Position getPosition();` and such. And then have your concrete ChessPiece classes implement these methods.

Comment: Try reading a tutorial on Java inheritance. Abstract classes might be closer to what you need. Reading the difference between an abstract class and an interface will probably also clear some things up for you.

Comment: Thanks you all for the answering,
@KLibby I will try again. I already saw some but didn't find any good tutorial that demonstrate a good use of interfaces. If you have a time to post an easy example, it's will help me a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong - interfaces are not made to connect similar attributes, but to connect classes with common behavior.
In order to get what you are looking for, you can use a 'getter' method - a method which returns a specific value. This way you force the implementing classes to create the attribute (or some kind of a substitute).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
You mean creating a getter with parameter that will force the class to create it? that's a good idea.

Do you have any easy example that show a good use of interfaces functionally?

I saw some tutorials and still didn't found a practice use for them..

Comment: @Smiled_One - Exactly. It is maybe somewhat hard to see the need in interfaces as it is hard to see what is the great use in functions when just learning to code. An interface lets you make a "contract" with other class writers, forcing them to create a behavior you expect to find when writing code using those classes. Example: running code in a new thread-you will have to create an object implementing the "Runnable" interface, which contains the run() method. In order to create a new thread, you will give a thread object your object, and it will look for the run() and run it in a new thread.

Comment: So from what you are saying interface are very useful when you work with team or build api and such...
But alone, it won't improve my efficient

Comment: A big part of programming is making a good design, which holds a good abstraction of what you are coding and its simplicity when trying to understand or change it - even when not coding in a team. Interface is one of the tools to make a good design. Also, it is required when using external code which needs objects implementing predefined interfaces, because it is expecting to find certain methods.

Answer (score 3):

> So my questions are if there is any work around for it?

For interfaces, not that I'm aware. But more importantly this is not what you would want to use interfaces for typically anyway. You want to use it as a contract for behavior (public methods), not for state (fields).

> if not, there is another way to put the same piece of code in different classes without make the variables static?

Sure, put those constructs in pretty much any class and they can be instance (non-static). Consider putting them in an AbstractClass if they need to be a necessary instance constituent of any class that inherits from this parent.

Better to have an interface for say `ChessPiece` and give it `public boolean isMoveValid(Position p);`, `public void makeMove(Position p);` public Position getPosition();` and such. And then have your concrete ChessPiece classes implement these methods.

```
public interface ChessPiece {
    public boolean isMoveValid(Position p);
    public void makeMove(Position p);
    public Position getPosition();
}
```

Assuming a Position class that holds rank and file.

Comment: Thank for the answer.
I think similar attributes are also part of common behavior, but you are right, I can put a really weird work around  when they will both will extended one weird abstract class.

I create a chess piece class with its rank and everything and its own move set.
Class work better and easier for me, I just wanted to add available move set for each soldier to the resolver without write it twice.

I still don't understand for what I will need interfaces.